# Books on composition as insightful as Goeschius

Tags: composition, harmony, counterpoint, teaching, orchestration

I've been a magpie for books on composition/orchestration, and it seems to me that the books written by Percy Goeschius are the best, most insightful and well-written that I've come across. Hia *Exercises in Melody Writing* contains heaps of insights about melody that subsume even Schoenberg's writings on the topic, and taught in a progressive way. Another similar golden nugget I've found over the years are translated writings on Partimento

Are there any similar such books on composition or orchestration?